# Change shipping address column format in Sales Order Grid (Magento 2.4.2)

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, order-grid, magento2.4.2

Where do I change the column shipping address format in the Sales => Order => Grid in Magento 2.4.2?
I need to have the post code/zip code in front of the city. "Stan" and "99999" should swap position and be on a new line.

Also, I want to remove the order grid linking, we only want to use the "View" link.

Thank you very much,

**Update!**
*Image describing the sales grid row linking issue. Is it possible to remove the row linking in sales => orders in Magento 2, and only use the action "View" link instead?*
**Update!**

**Image Grid Row Linking Issue**

[image: Grid Row Linking]

**Address Formatting Issue**

[image: Address formatting issue]

**Update #2 @Prince**

Should i remove the following whole part ...

```
<settings>
<childDefaults>
<param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid.sales_order_columns.actions</item>
<item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
<item name="params" xsi:type="array">
<item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>
<item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
</item>
</param>
</childDefaults>
</settings>
```

... and replace with:

```
<settings>
<childDefaults>
<param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">false</item>
</param>
</childDefaults>
</settings>
```

... to remove sales order grid linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement you need to create four new columns for the city, street, zip, and phone.

**1. So first of all create `sales_order_grid.xml` in your custom module**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <settings>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <column name="street">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Street</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="postcode">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Zip</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="city">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">City</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="telephone">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Phone</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**2. Create plugin for order collection data provider**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <plugin name="mageprince_custom_orders_grid" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrdersGrid" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/OrdersGrid.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class OrdersGrid
{
    public function afterGetReport($subject, $collection, $requestName)
    {
        if ($requestName !== 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
            return $collection;
        }

        if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_grid')) {
            $orderAddressTable  = $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_address');

            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['oat' => $orderAddressTable],
                'oat.parent_id = main_table.entity_id AND oat.address_type = \'shipping\'',
                ['telephone', 'city', 'postcode', 'street']
            );
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

That's it now you can see these columns in order grid as below

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have removed datasource class and updated the answer because datasource class not working with filters.

Comment: Thank you for your input Prince! This is also a good and working solution.

Comment: I will, and also upvote! Thanks again,

Comment: @Alldo To remove the link to the order grid you need to false to the provider in `fieldAction` param. Check file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml` in my updated answer

Comment: Really appreciate your help on this! I have updated my question (Update #2) as I have a lot of other information inside `<settings>...</settings>` in my modules `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml` ?

Comment: @Alldo Yes remove the whole `<settings>` and replace it with my answer's one.

Comment: Tried to make those changes, but if we click somewhere on a row, we are still redirect to the order detail page, so I'm afraid it doesn't work. I have cleared the cache, flushed Redis, deployed, but no luck. I know that file is working because we have disabled some mass print actions from the drop down meny. Any ideas? Thank you,

Comment: @Alldo This is a working solution and also tested by me. Please check other third-party modules which use the same `sales_order_grid.xml` and have `fiedaction`. If found then you need to remove it from there also.

Comment: I have found out that the extension Amasty Extended Order is responsible for the row linking via JS Knock Out (i believe). If I disable their extension, the row linking is gone. So your solution is working as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123579/discussion-between-alldo-and-prince-patel).

Comment: Last thought! Would it be possible to also make the 3 columns filterable? We receive a error if we click the labels in the grid. Thank you,

Comment: @Alldo Datasource class not working with filters. Check my answer on your new question for the solution about filter: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/336544/35758

Comment: @Alldo Also updated this answer so anyone who has the same problem can fix this. Let me know if you have any other issue

Answer (score 1):

The screen you show us is reliant on an order observer. When the order is successfully placed,

the event below is triggered and this will record the shipping address value as it appears in your order grid.

```
<event name="sales_order_process_relation">
        <observer name="sales_grid_order_sync_insert" instance="SalesOrderIndexGridSyncInsert" />
    </event>
```

For this observer to use a different format, you may create a custom module and in etc folder create a `di.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="ShippingAddressAggregatorPostCodeBeforeCity" type="Magento\Framework\DB\Sql\ConcatExpression">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">sales_shipping_address</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">company</item>
                </item>
                <item name="street" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">sales_shipping_address</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">street</item>
                </item>
                <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">sales_shipping_address</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">postcode</item>
                </item>
                <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">sales_shipping_address</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">city</item>
                </item>
                <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">sales_shipping_address</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">region</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="separator" xsi:type="string">, </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="shipping_address" xsi:type="object">ShippingAddressAggregatorPostCodeBeforeCity</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

finally, install the custom module. The orders that you will place after your new module is working will use the new format. The previous orders will remain with the previous format.

If you need the previous orders to be formatted correctly, it would be possible to use a command-line and apply a similar process

[repository](https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/shippingaddressformat/src/master/)

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works perfect! Great job! Do you also have a quick fix for removing the row linking in the sales orders grid, as asked in my post? Thanks again!

Comment: there is no hand on default Magento install, so my guess is your link is here because of a customisation that of course I can't advise unless I see the codebase. I can explain how to remove the view link, is it what you are after? I would not mind being a different question if I may

Comment: Yes that's right, please see update number 2 in my post. We use _Amasty Order Grid_ and _Amasty Order Action_, but the support staff at Amasty says that grid row linking is standard Magento behaviour, and not related to their extension. Beats me!

Comment: ok, hands up, I have not amasty order module installed.

Comment: So if they are telling the truth over at Amasty, the solution provided by @Prince Patel should work, right?

Comment: I admit I am at lost with the query now, best of luck. PLease do try @prince patel answer and if it helps you, that is a great outcome for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123574/discussion-between-alldo-and-herve-tribouilloy).

Comment: Thank you very much @Herve, I really appreciate your help. May I ask one last thing about your solution? The separator does not make any spaces after the comma, is that possible to add? `<argument name="separator" xsi:type="string">, </argument>` The column text looks like `"Streetname,9878,London"` instead of `"Street, Postcode, London"` Thank you,

Comment: yes, it is possible indeed. But it will have to be another question @alido

Answer (score 0):

try https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/address-templates.html

If doesn't help you need to do it trough custom code

Comment: No I'm sorry that doesn't do the trick.